# Can anyone identify the typeface used in this logo created in the 70's

Tags: logo, font-identification, slab-serif

Please help us to identify the typeface used to make "Marmot". Is it possible that it was hand-drawn very, very well? Not Stymie nor Rockwell

[image: Marmot Logo]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! Have you tried any of the sites listed in the  [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions?

Comment: Yes, we've tried them all. No true match. That's why we think it may have been hand-drawn.

Comment: The capital 'M' isn't vertically symmetrical, as you might expect. You can see minor differences on both halves. Plus other letters don't share the exact serif characteristics. This may hint it is hand drawn.

Comment: Thanks Doug! You are so right about the asymmetrical elements. I've always thought they were that way due to years of being reproduced via stat cameras and film. Slow degradation of original art. But maybe I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's some of those fonts with modifications, can't be?

This ones are the other screenshots:

[Street Corner Slab Bold font](http://www.whatfontis.com/Street-Corner-Slab-Bold.font?text=Marmot):

[image: Street Corner Slab Bold font]

---

This ones are the last ones:

[ITC Tyke Std Medium font](http://www.whatfontis.com/ITC-Tyke-Std-Medium-147314.font?text=Marmot):

[image: ITC Tyke Std Medium font]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the fonts in case the font were to be removed.

Comment: Ok, sorry :3

I'll post them under here!

Comment: I post them in separated answeres because I can't post more than two links per answer. I'm sorry.

Comment: In the future please make an edit to your answer and also take the [tour] on how the site works.  The format of the site is not a forum.